# Function to proccess array of objects into another structure?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I get an array of objects:

```
const inputStructure = [
  {
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test1'
  },
  {
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test2'
  },
  {
    state: 'TX',
    insurance: 'Test3'
  }
]
```

How can I group objects with the same `state` property?
I need to create a function which would return the following result:

```
const outputStructure = {
  'LA': {
    state: 'LA',
    insurances: ['Test1', 'Test2']
  },
  'TX': {
    state: 'TX',
    insurances: ['Test3']
  }
}
```

Comment: Familiarize yourself with [how to access and process nested objects, arrays or JSON](/q/11922383/4642212) and how to [create objects](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) and use the available static and instance methods of [`Object`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object#Static_methods) and [`Array`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Static_methods).

Comment: Have you looked at the `map` or `reduce` functions? These methods will help you iterate over the structure and create the new structure that you want.

Comment: Voted to close as a duplicate.  Many libraries have a `groupBy` function, and it's easy to write your own as seen in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```js
const inputStructure = [
  {
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test1'
  },
  {
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test2'
  },
  {
    state: 'TX',
    insurance: 'Test3'
  }
];

const data = {};

for (const item of inputStructure) {
  if (!data[item.state]) {
    data[item.state] = {
      state: item.state,
      insurances: []
    }
  }
  data[item.state].insurances.push(item.insurance);
}

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` array method to achieve it:

```js
const inputStructure = [{
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test1'
  },
  {
    state: 'LA',
    insurance: 'Test2'
  },
  {
    state: 'TX',
    insurance: 'Test3'
  }
]

const output = inputStructure.reduce((acc, e) => {
  acc[e.state] = ({
    state: e.state,
    insurances: (acc[e.state]?.insurances || []).concat(e.insurance)
  });
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(output)
```